# How to remove google acccount from my LG 4X HD/ P880

Tags: google-account, lg

I had my gmail account from an old employer disabled. It keeps on notifying me on "Account Action Required". I can only disable the sync in "Accounts and Settings", not remove it entirely. How do I remove it?

I use the 4.2 OEM OS.

Comment: Is it set as the primary Google account of the phone?

Comment: @onik No, I added it third

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be an option to remove non-primary Google accounts if you go to Settings -> Accounts & Sync -> (the Google account), tap the three-dot menu in the top right corner and select Remove Account.

Comment: Although in my case, I used the hardware "three dots" button